# How can I see details to grid in Vaadin flow?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin-flow

In my Vaadin flow project, I have a grid and I set some items but it shows like [grid data items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9kjN.png)

I want a decent format that a user can see specific details not like. Any idea or is there any component in vaadin to make this pretty?

Answer (score 4):

There are two options to do that:

- provide a better `ValueProvider` than the `.toString()`, that is used in your property right now.  E.g.

```java
grid.addColumn(person -> Integer.toString(person.getYearOfBirth()))
        .setHeader("Year of birth");
```

- `TemplateRenderer`: You can provide a "complex" HTML structure where to place content.  The docs contain an example: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-and-components-documentation/blob/master/documentation/components/tutorial-flow-grid.asciidoc#using-template-renderers E.g.:

```java
grid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.<Person> of("<b>[[item.name]]</b>")
              .withProperty("name", Person::getName)).setHeader("Name");
```